# Delete SQL using Prepared Statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, .post

Why doesn't the following block of quote work?

```
$uId=$_POST['uId'];
$cId=$_POST['cId'];
$query = "DELETE FROM pa65p_csBlog_postComment WHERE userId = :uId AND id = :cId";
$delete = $db -> prepare($query);
$delete -> bindParam(':uId', $uId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$delete -> bindParam(':cId', $cId, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if($result=$delete->execute()){
    echo 'success';
}
```

This is an ajax request using $.post. I keep getting internal server error 500 from this script. I've tried using a normal SQL request and i am able to get the script to work so there is no doubt my $_POST values are correct.

Comment: Check your PHP log for errors.

Comment: What is `$statement`?

Comment: Sorry. Re-edited the statement but still doesn't work. Tried checking the error log but it doesn't show. Unfortunately-^-

Answer (score 0):

```
if($delete=$statement->execute()){
    echo 'success';
}
```

here what is `$statement` ?. I think this must be `$delete->execute()`. Consider using `try catch` for error handling. [example](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#10)

Answer (score -1):

The if block contained $statement instead of $delete. Change that and it should work

```
    $uId=$_POST['uId'];
    $cId=$_POST['cId'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM pa65p_csBlog_postComment WHERE userId = :uId AND id = :cId";
    $delete = $db -> prepare($query);
    $delete -> bindParam(':uId', $uId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $delete -> bindParam(':cId', $cId, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    if($result=$delete->execute()){
        echo 'success';
    }
```